# VB.Net limit a text box to a range of values depending on the combobox selection

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, combobox, textbox

I am trying to limit the user from entering a value over a certain amount into a textbox depending on their selection from a combo box.

I have got a combo box with 1 Pallet ... 10 Pallets. The maximum weight per pallet is 1000kgs. So if 1 pallet is selected the user cannot enter more than 1000kgs, if 2 pallets are selected they cannot enter over 2000kgs, and so on. Also they cannot enter a value of less than or equal to 0 at any time.

I have been playing around with this for hours now and its driving me mad. The following code is what I have got so far. Please note, it is part of an IF statement, hence the elseif.

Its working for 1 pallet but when I add the second pallet, the first pallet bit works but not the second.

Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

```
    Dim Jweight As Integer
    Jweight = WeightTextBox.Text

    ElseIf combopallets.SelectedItem = "1 Pallet" And Jweight <= "0" Or Jweight > "1000" OrElse combopallets.SelectedItem = "2 Pallets" And Jweight <= "0" Or Jweight > "2000" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid weight." & vbCrLf & "Maximum of 1000kgs per pallet.", "Invaild", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        WeightTextBox.Select()
        If WeightTextBox.SelectionLength = 0 Then
            WeightTextBox.SelectAll()
            Jweight = 0
        End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having the issue becuase, among other things, you're doing arithmetic comparisons such as `<=` or `>` using strings (`Jweight <= "0"` ... There is b big difference between `0` and `"0"`!!)

One way you could code this would look as follows:

```
Jweight = Integer.Parse(WeightTextBox.Text)

If Jweight <= 0 Or _
  (combopallets.SelectedItem = "1 Pallet" And Jweight > 1000) Or _
  (combopallets.SelectedItem = "2 Pallets" And Jweight > 2000) Then

     ... Put in your error code ...

End If
```

Hope that helps!!

**UPDATE:**

To make this work for more than 2 Pallets, you could use better logic than the multiple `Or` statements... I'd suggest something along the lines of:

```
Jweight = Integer.Parse(WeightTextBox.Text)

' Since we know your combobox will have, in index(0), "1 Pallet" 
' and will continue such that at index(n) it will have "n+1 Pallets"
' Just find its selected index and add 1 to know how many pallets were selected
Dim NumberOfPallets As Integer = combopallets.SelectedIndex + 1

If Jweight <= 0 Or (Jweight > NumberOfPallets * 1000) Then

  ... Put in your error code ...

End If
```

Don't know if this would help you, but it just forms a more robust solution with fewer lines of code....

Comment: brilliant, you absolute star! :) thank you sooo much. Just got to put the other 8 pallets in now :P

Comment: @CaraRichardson, Gald it helpd! - But, given that you're going all the way up to 8 (or in other words, more than 2), I'd suggest doing it differently than a bunch of `OR` statements in your `If`... Can you tell me, will the list be "1 pallet", "2 pallets" ... "8 pallets" and each one raises the weight by 1000?

Comment: Theres 10 pallets in total. The max weight per pallet is 1000kgs. If I am being completely honest as long as it works I am happy. Its for my final year project and I have only got 4 weeks left n I have still got a report to finish. So as long as it works I am safe :)

Comment: I'm adding in more code for you to play with now if you want it... Look at the updated answer...